# Why is preventDefault not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Here is my javascript code. The commented line works:

```js
$("#regForm").submit(function(event) {
  // event.preventDefault()
  password = $("#inputPassword3")
  login = $("#inputEmail3")
  user_instance = 0
  $.ajax({
      url: "{{ url_for('get_users') }}",
      method: 'POST'
    }).done(function(data) {
      data.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.username == login.val() || item.mail == login.val()) {
          user_instance = item
        }
      })
      pass_arr = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(password.val())
      hash = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(pass_arr)
      console.log(hash, user_instance.passwd)
      if (hash != user_instance.passwd) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log("+")
        password.attr("style", "border:#f00 solid 1px")
        password.attr("placeholder", "Wrong password")
      }
```

`event.preventDefault()` is not working here:

```
<div id="regForm">
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('login') }}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email/Login</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="imput" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email/Login" name="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="sign-in">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

It submits form anyway, even though color of form changing, why is that? When uncommented `preventDefault()` is working as should be

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. The first example is commented, yet you say it works. The second HTML block has no reference to preventDefault, yet you say it doesn't work. That makes no sense.

Comment: You call `event.preventDefault()` to late, you can't use it in an ajax callback.

Comment: you need to change id of form to regForm in order to work with your code. Form has default behaviour not div. just change id and test.

Comment: I did same with click on button, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('body').on('submit', 'YOUR-ID' ,function(event) {}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17850916)

Comment: yes you are right, I am working hard to get that reputation @Styx